# 'irritated' vs. 'aggravated'

Tags: meaning

Which is more correct?

> The constant itching over the last week left him quite *aggravated*.
>
> The constant itching over the last week left him quite *irritated*.

> Merriam Webster
>
> irritated : subjected to irritation; especially : roughened, reddened,
>   or inflamed by an irritant
>
> aggravate : to produce inflammation in

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, and the desired meaning will govern your choice. Close General Reference.

Comment: Merriam Webster's "Usage" note should have clarified this matter for you. I endorse ΜετάEd's call to close.

Comment: I'm both irritated and aggravated by the recent plethora of questions regarding possible synonyms and their possible differences. That, by the way, was [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology) - I have no way of distinguishing my irritation from my aggravation, apart from saying that *aggravation* doesn't seem such a good word in that particular context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I, on the other hand, find that my irritation was aggravated by this latest instance.

Comment: Why is nobody irrigated by this whole question?

Comment: @StoneyB: I'll buy that as a valid usage. Google Books ["his irritation was"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22his+irritation+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):11,600 results, ["his aggravation was"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22his+aggravation+was%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):238 results. And ["irritation was aggravated"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22irritation+was+aggravated%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 330 results, whereas *"aggravation was irritated"* gets none at all.

Comment: @Robusto This has nothing to do with agriculture.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Google? *Books*? I cock my snoot and arrogate authority to myself.

Comment: @Robusto  With any luck, the question will shortly be abrogated by closure.

Comment: @StoneyB: Google Books again - ["cock my snoot"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cock+my+snoot%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):0 results, ["cock a snoot"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cock+a+snoot%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):518, ["cock my snook"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cock+my+snook%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):1 result, ["cock a snook"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cock+a+snook%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):8020 results. I think it's inherent in the nature of language that you have to take *some* notice of what others say/write.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Hmm ... I have been be-fooled by East Alabama folk etymology. I shall have to dine on sparrowgrass.

Comment: @StoneyB: I can certainly see the problem there. OED says the origin of *snook=derisory gesture* is "obscure". But *snoot=nose* is definitely from *snout*, and the *snook* gesture does involve putting the thumb of an open palm against the nose, so it's easy to conflate them. Perhaps someone else on ELU could extend OED's etymology for *cock a snook*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the words in their conventional sense, and then quoting medical definitions that aren't applicable.

In conventional usage, "irritate" and "aggravate" both mean to annoy. "Aggravate" implies causing frustration, like someone repeatedly blocks your progress. "Irritate" is more general. Either works in your example and they both mean essentially the same thing.

"Aggravate" can also mean to make a situation worse. Like, "The long hike made us tired and hungry. Than it started raining, which aggravated our discomfort."

In the more medical sense, "irritate" is to adversely stimulate a bodily organ, usually causing inflammation, etc. "The caustic acid irritated his skin." "Aggravate" in a medical context means to make an illness or physical problem worse. "The patient's condition was aggravated by his poor diet."

I have never heard "aggravate" used to mean "produce inflammation", nor did I find this definition in my dictionary. Maybe you'd find that in a technical medical dictionary.

Comment: MW Medical Dictionary: 
Main Entry:       
aggravate

Function:         
transitive verb

1 : to make worse, more serious, or more severe <movement may aggravate the pain> 
2 : to produce inflammation in : IRRITATE <surgery aggravated the nerve>

Comment: Main Entry:       
irritate

Function:         
verb

transitive verb 
1 : to provoke impatience, anger, or displeasure in 
2 : to cause (an organ or tissue) to be irritable : produce irritation in <harsh soaps may irritate the skin> 
3 : to produce excitation in (as a nerve) : cause (as a muscle) to contract 
intransitive verb : to induce irritation

Comment: All medical dictionaries are technical. But common usage and medical usage are sometimes worlds apart (apt cliché). I've been finding that for the past 15 years of biomedical editing.

Comment: @BillFranke Hmm. I didn't intend to say that that was not a valid medical definition of "aggravate", just that I'd never heard it. Interesting.

Comment: I just wanted to put that definition on record. These are not words I see every day in medical papers. I always verify my word choices with the dictionary, even when I know the word well, just to be sure that my memory isn't playing tricks on me.